# shell script: use pipelines instead of files for batch processing

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I'm using these two commands in order to process a huge single sequence of json objects:

```
$ jq -c '.[]' csvjson.json | split -l 25 - splitted
```

Above command, creates several `splitted-*` files, containing 25 lines each one.

```
$ jq --slurp 'map({PutRequest: {Item: map_values({S: .})}})' splitted-n > output-n.json
```

Is there any way to pipeline above two commands?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to pipeline above two commands?

We can make use of the `split --filter` option:

```
jq -c '.[]' csvjson.json |
split -l25 --filter='jq --slurp "map({PutRequest: {Item: map_values({S: .})}})" >$FILE.json' - output
```